# How to multi thread a function in bash?

Tags: bash, ping

I have written a bash script for ping sweep, but for hosts which are down it's taking more time, so I tried to multi-thread the get_ip function, by using `&` at the end. However that doesn't seem to work. How can I write a script to achieve this faster?

```
#!/bin/bash
get_ip () {
  ping -c 1 $1.$i 1>/dev/null 
  if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "Host $1.$i is up"
  else 
    echo "$1.$i is down" 
  fi 
}
if [ $1 ];then
  for i in {0..255}; 
  do 
    get_ip "$1" &
  done
else 
  echo "Enter the IP address to scan"
fi
```

Comment: You say "However that doesn't seem to work." In what way? Are you asking about the bug, or how to make it faster? Show us what happened, and tell us what you expect.

Comment: I am getting two prompts as if I am executing the script separately two times I expect it to run as a whole and report the online hosts. Any idea how I can do this??

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with the speed of this. It very quickly does the wrong thing. You problem is with the variable names. `i` and `1` look similar. do not confuse them.

Also in a function `$1` is the functions input (i.e. command line argument), not the scripts input.

So let us make some fixes:

The function now uses its input (the whole IP address).

```
#!/bin/bash
get_ip () {
  ping -c 1 $1 1>/dev/null 
  if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "Host $1 is up"
  else 
    echo "$1 is down" 
  fi 
}
```

The main now creates a whole IP address, to pass to the function.

```
if [ $1 ];then
  for i in {0..255}; 
  do 
    get_ip "$1.$i" &
  done
else 
  echo "Enter the first 3 octets of the IP address to scan, as the 1st argument of this script."
fi
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the edit now it looks more clear.

Comment: @Pyroot your comment is on this answer. Is it about my edit to the question?

Comment: Yes, it is @ctrl-alt-delor